# Symfony 3 - Parameter's default value not returned

Tags: symfony, null, routes, default-value, symfony-3.3

I'm trying to learn Symfony so i'm very new to it and this is probably a silly question but still, I can't find the answer.

---

### SETUP

I use the latest version of Symfony (got it today) and the latest WAMP with PHP 7.1.9. 
I have a Symfony project named "Project" with one bundle : SSTestBundle. 
In "src/SS/BlogBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml" i have the following route :

```
ss_blog_home:
    path: /{page}
    defaults: 
        _controller: SSBlogBundle:Discussion:index
        page: 1
    requirements:
        page: \d*
```

I have a controller named DiscussionController, with the following function :

```
public function indexAction($page)
{
    if ($page < 1)
    {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException('Page -'.$page.'- not existing.');
    }

    return $this->render('OCPlatformBundle:Advert:index.html.twig');
}
```

So, if the value of my "page" parameter is invalid, I get a 404 page with the "Page -X- not existing" message. And if the page number is correct, it displays a very basic template to say hello.

---

### PROBLEM

If I access my project with "localhost/web/Project/", I get the message : "Page -- not existing". Everything seems to work fine except that $page is not equal to 1 but to nothing !

If I access my project with "localhost/web/Project/5", it displays the page as it should.

If I access my project with "localhost/web/Project/0", it displays the error page as it should, with "Page -0- not existing".

BUT ! If I change my route from '/{page}' to '/test/{page}' and try to access "localhost/web/Project/test/", it works fine and the page is displayed !

Any idea why it returns a null default value for 'page' only if I set my route to the root folder ? T_T

Comment: Why do not try `page: \d+`?

Comment: Which version exactly are you using? Why are you configuring the routing like this anyway? You can make all of your controllers to get autowired and configured with annotations. Don't need to touch any configuration at all.

Answer (score 1):

Some important conclusions:

- You made 'page' parameter optional (using in the defaults a default value for 'page'). This means that even if you don't send it in the request, the code will use its default value. So, accesing localhost/web/Project/ should also trigger the controller - and it does.
- You put in the requirements this regex: '**\d***' - this means that the 'page' could be even an empty string or at least a digit. If you want to solve Problem nr 1, you should use '**\d+**' .
- Remember that routes can be overidden and the first route defined always win.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Symfony 3 documentation on routing (see [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html#)), you should be able to set up your default route parameter like so:

```
ss_blog_home:
    path: /{page}
    defaults: { _controller: SSBlogBundle:Discussion:index, page: 1 } # this sets the default page number for the route to 1.
    requirements:
        page: '\d+' # this line requires that a digit of length 1 or more is passed in to the route.
```

Comment: Just updated my answer with a link to the documentation where I found the answer to OP's question. There's likely an issue with OP's implementation using a YAML list instead of a dict/hash with the value set to an object with the controller action and default params.

Answer (score 0):

- If I access my project with "localhost/web/Project/", I get the message : "Page -- not existing". Everything seems to work fine except that $page is not equal to 1 but to nothing !
  **Because you are asking route to have one parameter but you are sending none**
- If I access my project with "localhost/web/Project/5", it displays the page as it should.
  **Because you are sending parameter**
- If I access my project with "localhost/web/Project/5", it displays the page as it should.
  **Because you are sending parameter**
- If I access my project with "localhost/web/Project/0", it displays the error page as it should, with "Page -0- not existing".
  **Because of condition**
- BUT ! If I change my route from '/{page}' to '/test/{page}' and try to access "localhost/web/Project/test/", it works fine and the page is displayed !
  **Because of condition**
  Code not looks for type of page so you can send anything you like and it will work

  if ($page < 1)
  {
      throw new NotFoundHttpException('Page -'.$page.'- not existing.');
  }

Answer (score 0):

By the name of your bundle "OCPlatformBundle" I guess you followed the [Openclassroom Symfony tutorial](https://openclassrooms.com/courses/developpez-votre-site-web-avec-le-framework-symfony). So I assume that you have a prefix for your routes and hit the same problem as me. At first I didn't understand too but I found that it's indeed a limitation of Symfony when you prefix your routes !

- [[Routing] configure trailing slash on imported routes #12141](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/12141)
- [[2.2] Importing Routes (Prefix issue) #4322](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/4322)
- [[Routing] Defaults
  parameters with annotation and prefix #5767](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/5767)

Comment: Fixed in Symfony 4.1 https://github.com/symfony/symfony/commit/7262c5973de57f0771ea04b9824d7fdfd3267ca9

Answer (score 0):

It seems the default parameter needs to be given in the Twig side. e.g.

```
HTML... {{ path(ss_blog_home, {'page': 1 }) }} HTML
```